# better while loop structure in python

Tags: python, loops

I have a function `remove_it()` that tries to remove some data and the removed data is added to the set `removed`. The main logic is that if there is more to remove, keep removing and my code looks like this:

```
    removed = set()
    prev_count = -1

    while prev_count != len(removed):
        prev_count = len(removed)
        remove_it()
```

It bothers me a little that the `while` loop condition and the next line look very similar to each other. Is it normal or is there a better way to do it?

The logic in `remove_it()` is quite complicated: it detects some graph structure topology and after each round of removal the topology changes and I cannot know how it changes until the removal is done.

I was thinking of return bool value from `remove_it()` to track whether the set `removed` has changed. Then the while loop would be like

```
while remove_it():
     pass
```

which is also strange to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: could you give somme examples of  the data? might help to better understand the problem/come up with an optimal solution

Comment: Interesting. In C, my stronger language, this would indeed be `while(function()) ;` -- note the *explicit* semicolon. Nothing like that for Python?

Comment: The second looks quite natural. Perhaps a rename to `remove()` and we are done: you thus say, "while removing, keep going".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `remove_it` function has side effects and this makes program harder to read. You can rewrite it so that instead of modifying global `removed` variable it would return set of removed values. Then you can rewrite the loop:

```
removed = set()

while True:
    removed_batch = remove_it()
    if removed_batch:
        removed += removed_batch
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Best advice ever, when a function act outside it's own scope, makes it return what it did or a true/false value, more idiomatic on usage and easier to maintain on long term.